# Jolt converts comma separated array to array

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I'm new to JOLT.
This is the transformation I'm trying to achieve:

The input json is an object that is comma separated. The input json looks like this:

```
{
  "Ids": {
    "IND": {
      "IND-ADR": {
        "id": "ind-adr-id",
        "key": "ind1"
      },
      "IND-PAN": {
        "id": "ind-pan-id",
        "key": "ind2"
      }
    },
    "USA": {
      "USA-SSN": {
        "id": "usa-ssn-id",
        "key": "usa1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output looks like 3 separate items of a list. Expected output:

```
{
  "Ids": [
    {
      "country": "IND",
      "IdType": "IND-ADR",
      "id": "ind-adr-id",
      "key": "ind1"
    },
    {
      "country": "IND",
      "IdType": "IND-PAN",
      "id": "ind-pan-id",
      "key": "ind2"
    },
    {
      "country": "USA",
      "IdType": "USA-SSN",
      "id": "usa-ssn-id",
      "key": "usa1"
    }
  ]
}
```

My output:

```
{
  "country" : [ "IND", "USA" ],
  "IdType" : [ "IND-ADR", "IND-PAN", "USA-SSN" ],
  "id" : [ "ind-adr-id", "ind-pan-id", "usa-ssn-id" ],
  "Key" : [ "ind1", "ind2", "usa1" ]
}
```

My jolt spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Ids": {
        "*": {
          "$": "country",
          "*": {
            "$": "IdType",
            "*": "&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the expected output using the jolt spec transformation. I am using the Jolt demo website to play around and would really appreciate some help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spec is pretty good but misses the following :

- separation by identifiers such as ***&1***, ***&2***, ***&3*** taken from different levels
- invoking every pairs from the deepest level, eg. you might add country to the innermost level as well by using ***$1*** representation

So the following transformation will handle the issue

```json
[
  { // separation of objects
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Ids": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "$1": "&2_&1.&3.country", // &3 needed to keep the literal "Ids" for the next spec
            "$": "&2_&1.&3.IdType",
            "*": "&2_&1.&3.&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&1[#3].&" //&1 represents going one level and copying the key, eg. "Ids"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]